# MySQL: Importing csv into table with quotation marks

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, sql-insert, load-data-infile

I have a csv where each row starts with quotation marks and ends with them too. How do I ignore the quotations at the start and end of the row when loading the csv into a table?

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/data.csv' 
INTO TABLE test1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\"\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

I have tried

```
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

but this refers to each specific field and not the entire row.

Comment: Lines starting by ... terminating by ...

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Shadow and Barmar, the answer lies in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) :

> If all the input lines have a common prefix that you want to ignore, you can use LINES STARTING BY 'prefix_string' to skip the prefix and anything before it. If a line does not include the prefix, the entire line is skipped. [...] The FIELDS TERMINATED BY, LINES STARTING BY, and LINES TERMINATED BY values can be more than one character.

Hence, use :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/data.csv' 
INTO TABLE test1 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
    LINES STARTING BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '"\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```